# PHP prepared statement loop JOIN query not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I am trying to gather some variables from my query then output them using `$stmt->bind_result()` however I am not getting any rows returned in my search.

I am not sure what is going wrong here?

```
  $tag = trim($_GET['tag']);

  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT trips.trip_id FROM trips JOIN tags ON trips.post_id = tags.post_id WHERE tag = ?');
  $stmt->bind_param('s', $tag);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_result($id);    

  while ($stmt->fetch()) {

      echo $id;

  }
```

Comment: What does `$tag` contain exactly and what does the query return when you run it directly in mysql? Also, you should add error handling to your database calls. The easiest way to do that in mysqli, is to have it throw exceptions. Just add this to the top of your script: `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); `

Comment: Did you run your query on your database? Via phpmyadmin or some other tool. Did it return rows?